# Why does word2vec only take one task for mapPartitionsWithIndex at Word2Vec.scala:323

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I am running *word2vec* in spark and when it comes to `fit()`, only one task is observed in UI as in image:

[image].

As per the configuration, `num-executors = 1000, executor-cores = 2`. And the RDD coalesces to 2000 partitions. It takes quite a long time for `mapPartitionsWithIndex`. Can it be distributed to multiple executors or tasks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setNumPartitions(numPartitions: Int)` solves my problem. I did not check the default value.
Sets number of partitions (default: 1).

Comment: There is a caveat to set `numPartitions` to higher than 1, the accuracy may suffer based on the documentation. "Sets number of partitions (default: 1). Use a small number for accuracy."